# PHP to DOC - CSS and images not being applied in doc file

Tags: php, html, css, doc

I am creating doc file with the help of PHP.
 **doc.php:**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='\Content-Type\' content='\text/html'; charset='Windows-1252'>";
echo "<head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../doc.css'></head>"; 
echo "<body>";
echo "<b>My first document</b><img src='../images/logo.png'>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

After executing this file  'document_name.doc' file is being created but without applying css and image.

Any solution?

Comment: Is the CSS and image in the relative location you have specified?

Comment: Yes..If i would execute this file without headers() it gives me a simple php file output with applying properly css and images on the page.

Comment: Given that the CSS and images are relative to the document root on the webserver, how do you expect MS Word to know where the server is when you open this file on a client PC

Comment: Note that you aren't actually creating a native BIFF-format .doc file, simply a file of html markup with a .doc extension

Comment: These all on localhost only.Created doc file is not getting the path of css and image.In addition, whichever the doc file is created i have to transfer it on another Local PC in which i am also facing same problem which is obvious.

Comment: That's my point: MS Word has no idea where those relative links are supposed to be, just that some webserver somewhere on the great interweb has a file called `logo.png` somewhere in a folder or subfolder called `images`... if you do it this way, you need to provide a full (not a relative, but a full) URL (including the `http://myservername.com/`).... and that server needs to be accessible from anywhere that your users might open the file in MS Word

Comment: An alternative is to include the css (rather than a link to the css) in the actual file that you're generating, and to embed the images using `<img src="data:image/png;base64...">`

Comment: Your suggestion is quiet good, but my application is going to work on local host only, In offline mode. CSS problem will be solved by using inline css but what about images?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's localhost or not.... MS Word doesn't know that you have a local webserver running on localhost and that it should use that; and even if it did, it wouldn't be able to find a file at `../images/logo.png`. I've told you how to handle images when offline: by embedding the image data in your markup using `<img src="data:image/png;base64...">`

Comment: The alternative is what @ekaratas has mentioned in his answer, using PHPWord to create a real MS Word file (I am one of the developers of that library) rather than using HTML markup

Comment: the Office Open XML File SolarSystem.docx of folder examples not being opened because there are problems with its contents. After opening SolarSystem.docx  file it showing "the file is corrupt and cannot be opened"

Answer (score 1):

You may try this wtih headers:

```
<html>
    <meta http-equiv='\Content-Type\' content='\text/html'; charset='Windows-1252'>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../doc.css'>
    </head>
    <body>enter code here
        <b>My first document</b>
        <img src='../images/logo.png'>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you design and create a word document you may look at [PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/)